# Detecting keystrokes in Julia

Tags: julia, keystroke

I have a piece of code in Julia in which a solver iterates many, many times as it seeks a solution to a very complex problem. At present, I have to provide a number of iterations for the code to do, set low enough that I don't have to wait hours for the code to halt in order to save the current state, but high enough that I don't have to keep activating the code every 5 minutes.

Is there a way, with the current state of Julia (0.2), to detect a keystroke instructing the code to either end without saving (in case of problems) or end with saving? I require a method such that the code will continue unimpeded unless such a keystroke event has happened, and that will interrupt on any iteration.

Essentially, I'm looking for a command that will read in a keystroke if a keystroke has occurred (while the terminal that Julia is running in has focus), and run certain code if the keystroke was a specific key. Is this possible?

Note: I'm running julia via xfce4-terminal on Xubuntu, in case that affects the required command.

Comment: What you want to do is in the area of terminal programming. It usually involves modifying the current tty and then listening for keystrokes. I'm not aware of any packages in julia that let you do this currently though.

Comment: I've found a way to achieve the results I wanted through a Tk GUI implementation with "Save" triggering the code to stop on the next iteration and "Cancel" triggering an error to stop the code without saving. I'm leaving the question open because my solution doesn't provide a method of detecting keystrokes, and there needs to be a keystroke detection method for Julia.

Answer (score 3):

You can you an asynchronous task to read from STDIN, blocking until something is available to read.   In your main computation task, when you are ready to check for input, you can call yield() to lend a few cycles to the read task, and check a global to see if anything was read.  For example:

```
input = ""
@async while true
    global input = readavailable(STDIN)
end
for i = 1:10^6 # some long-running computation                                  
    if isempty(input)
        yield()
    else
        println("GOT INPUT: ", input)
        global input = ""
    end
    # do some other work here                                                   
end
```

Note that, since this is cooperative multithreading, there are no race conditions.

Comment: Thank you for your idea, but I can't seem to get this to work. If I have it loop 1:10 and make it perform reduce(*,1:big(500000)) to give it something slow to do in the "do some other work here" part, then type something in while it's running, it doesn't stop at all (for input, I mean - it just runs until it has finished processing). This is true both if run regularly and if run with an extra process (julia -p 1). I'm using 0.2.1 - could this be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to achieve this by sending an interrupt (`Ctrl+C`). This should work from the REPL without any changes to your code – if you want to implement saving you'll have to handle the resulting `InterruptException` and prompt the user.

Comment: Is there a way to make the code continue from the point it was at when the exception was thrown? Without something like that, I cannot see how to deal with the situation in which the exception is thrown while the important variables are in the process of being updated.

Comment: I think the only way to do that would be to repeat the exception handler at those points (perhaps using a macro to avoid too much repetition).

Answer (score 2):

I had some trouble with the answer from steven-g-johnson, and ended up using a `Channel` to communicate between tasks:

```
function kbtest()
    # allow 'q' pressed on the keyboard to break the loop
    quitChannel = Channel(10)
    @async while true
        kb_input = readline(stdin)
        if contains(lowercase(kb_input), "q")
            put!(quitChannel, 1)
            break
        end
    end

    start_time = time()
    while (time() - start_time) < 10
        if isready(quitChannel)
            break
        end

        println("in loop @ $(time() - start_time)")
        sleep(1)
    end

    println("out of loop @ $(time() - start_time)")
end
```

This requires pressing  and then , which works well for my needs.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! Note STDIN is now lowercase stdin since a few Julia versions.

Comment: @krookedking Thanks for the heads up re: `stdin`, I Just updated the answer. Also, FYI Steven Johnson's answer does work for me if I change `STDIN` to `stdin` in his answer; I'm using julia 1.8.2